# Xcode won't compile for iPhone 6

Tags: ios, xcode, arm64

I have an old project which compiles well on my iPhone 4, but when I try to compile for my iPhone 6 I encounter this star`can't specifiy -Q with -arch arm64`

what does it mean? does any one have any idea?

here a shot of my project setting:
the second one is my project subModule meeting shot:
[image]

[image]

```
CompileC /Users/hashem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iGolestanWorkSpace-adtgzikxceksufgpstzqxkjvkepa/Build/Intermediates/iGolestan.build/Debug-iphoneos/iGolestan.build/Objects-normal/arm64/maxvid_decode_arm.o AVAnimator/maxvid_decode_arm.s normal arm64 assembler-with-cpp com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd "/Users/hashem/Desktop/Xcode Projects/Gulestan"
export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x assembler-with-cpp -arch arm64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wmissing-prototypes -Wunreachable-code -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -iquote /Users/hashem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iGolestanWorkSpace-adtgzikxceksufgpstzqxkjvkepa/Build/Intermediates/iGolestan.build/Debug-iphoneos/iGolestan.build/iGolestan-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/hashem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iGolestanWorkSpace-adtgzikxceksufgpstzqxkjvkepa/Build/Intermediates/iGolestan.build/Debug-iphoneos/iGolestan.build/iGolestan-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/hashem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iGolestanWorkSpace-adtgzikxceksufgpstzqxkjvkepa/Build/Intermediates/iGolestan.build/Debug-iphoneos/iGolestan.build/iGolestan-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/hashem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iGolestanWorkSpace-adtgzikxceksufgpstzqxkjvkepa/Build/Intermediates/iGolestan.build/Debug-iphoneos/iGolestan.build/iGolestan-project-headers.hmap -iquote../OHAttributedLabel -I/Users/hashem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iGolestanWorkSpace-adtgzikxceksufgpstzqxkjvkepa/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/hashem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iGolestanWorkSpace-adtgzikxceksufgpstzqxkjvkepa/Build/Intermediates/iGolestan.build/Debug-iphoneos/iGolestan.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -I/Users/hashem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iGolestanWorkSpace-adtgzikxceksufgpstzqxkjvkepa/Build/Intermediates/iGolestan.build/Debug-iphoneos/iGolestan.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/hashem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iGolestanWorkSpace-adtgzikxceksufgpstzqxkjvkepa/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -no-integrated-as -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/hashem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iGolestanWorkSpace-adtgzikxceksufgpstzqxkjvkepa/Build/Intermediates/iGolestan.build/Debug-iphoneos/iGolestan.build/Objects-normal/arm64/maxvid_decode_arm.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/hashem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iGolestanWorkSpace-adtgzikxceksufgpstzqxkjvkepa/Build/Intermediates/iGolestan.build/Debug-iphoneos/iGolestan.build/Objects-normal/arm64/maxvid_decode_arm.dia -c /Users/hashem/Desktop/Xcode\ Projects/Gulestan/AVAnimator/maxvid_decode_arm.s -o /Users/hashem/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iGolestanWorkSpace-adtgzikxceksufgpstzqxkjvkepa/Build/Intermediates/iGolestan.build/Debug-iphoneos/iGolestan.build/Objects-normal/arm64/maxvid_decode_arm.o

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/as: can't specifiy -Q with -arch arm64
clang: error: assembler command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please put here all compile log. Before compiling, please make clean.

Comment: What version of Xcode?  It looks to me that you either need to update the version or reinstall as it looks corrupt.

Comment: @Droppy thanks for answer I'm using Xcode 6.1

Comment: OK try 6.3.1 (not 6.3.2).

Comment: @MoDJ how did you understand? post as an answer to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to compile AVAnimator/maxvid_decode_arm.s which is 32 bit ARM asm code under the ARM64 built target. You will need to update the version of the AVAnimator library that you have embedded into your app to the github HEAD in order to compiler for ARM64.